# MySQL create / select adds fields from the source table

Tags: mysql

I encountered an issue with MySQL, adding fields from the *selected* source table.

Here is an example (you can find it on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be118b) :

```
CREATE TABLE source_table (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  foo VARCHAR(3),
  INDEX (id)
);
INSERT INTO source_table (id, foo) VALUES (1, "one");

// Create another table and fill it from the source_table
CREATE TABLE example_table (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  bar VARCHAR (3),
  INDEX (id)
) SELECT 
  source_table.id,
  source_table.foo
FROM source_table
WHERE source_table.id = 1;
```

In the end, my `example_table` will have a `foo` field, that I never requested to be create.
Plus, `bar` will be empty while `foo` will be filled.

---

The solution I found is to use **aliases** for each field, but it's redundant:

```
CREATE TABLE example_table (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  bar VARCHAR (3),
  INDEX (id)
) SELECT 
  source_table.id AS id,
  source_table.foo AS bar
FROM source_table
WHERE source_table.id = 1;
```

Is there any trick in MySQL's configuration to avoid this behaviour? I feel like it would create surprising tables.

Comment: You can create a View if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the documented behaviour of [insert ... select ...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html), so there is no way to configure it to avoid this behaviour:

> MySQL creates new columns for all elements in the SELECT. For example:
>
> ```
> mysql> CREATE TABLE test (a INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     ->        PRIMARY KEY (a), KEY(b))
>     ->        ENGINE=MyISAM SELECT b,c FROM test2;
> ```
>
> This creates a MyISAM table with three columns, a, b, and c.